# Strpos not working

Tags: php

I need to see if the **URL** the user is currently on closely matches (So contains) the URL in the database. However strpos doesn't seem to be doing the job correctly.

This is the code i'm using

```
if(strpos($row['url'], $currenturl) === 0) {
    echo "YEAH!";
    return true;
}
echo "Current URL: ".$currenturl." Permission URL: ".$row['url']." Strpos ".strpos($row['url'], $currenturl)."<br>";
```

And this is the debug output.

> Current URL: projects/projectview.php?whmcsid=0&id=4 Permission URL: projects/projectview.php?whmcsid=0 Strpos

So its not matching. Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/GUoFp. `var_dump` your urls, maybe there're extra spaces or new lines. If true - `trim` them.

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid order of arguments. `strpos` searches in `haystack` for a `needle`, so:

```
if(strpos($currenturl, $row['url']) === 0) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get to know the substring is absent, you must use,

```
   ===FALSE
```

as 0 may also indicate the starting position of the substring.

Comment: He wants the starting position, not FALSE.

Comment: my bad. It should be then !==FALSE

Comment: no it should stay === 0 as 0 in this case is the starting position.